# asp.net application + single sign on

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I want to implement single sign on in my asp.net web application. Scenario is something like below:

1. user will get registered / sign up at "account.example.com"
2. there will a link to "professional.example.com"
3. when user goes to this link (step 2), they must remain logged in over here.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property on the cookie object to ".example.com" and it will work for any sub-domain of "example.com".

If you're using ASP.NET's forms authentication, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) is a good place to start to find out all the options for configuring it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Forms Authentication you need to set your forms and machinekey sections in web.config to be identical.

Here is a good link -> [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)